# Does Flurry of Blows count as a full attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, attack

In Pathfinder, does using FoB count as a full attack for purposes such as using Medusa's Wrath?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

It's right there in the first line of [Flurry of Blows](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk#TOC-Flurry-of-Blows-Ex-) 
(emphasis mine):

> Starting at 1st level, a monk can make a flurry of blows **as a full-attack action**.

Flurry of blows is specifically a full-**attack** action, rather than a special full-round action.